# Delphi Prism : Is this deepcopy or shallowcopy?

Tags: .net, object, clone, delphi-prism

Take a look at the following code:

```
method TMakerRect.Clone: TMakerObject;
var
  newRect:TMakerRect;
begin
  newRect := new TMakerRect(bounds,myForm);
  newRect.Assign(Self);
  newRect.theBrushStyle := Self.theBrushStyle;
  Result := newRect;
end;

method TMakerGraphic.Assign(obj:TMakerObject);
begin
  inherited Assign(obj);
  if obj is TMakerGraphic then
  begin
       thePen:=TmakerGraphic(obj).thePen;
       FillColor:=TMakerGraphic(obj).fillColor;
       dynamics:=TmakerGraphic(obj).dynamics;
  end;
end;
```

I am thinking that this is how you would do deepcopy cloning of an object. If that is true, these objects should act as if they are separate object, but it doesn't. Any time I change, for instance, thepen's width it also changes the thepen width of the original object. Please, help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a shallow clone; `thePen` is not cloned but shared between the two instances.

Instead of

```
newRect.Assign(Self);
```

you should clone each individual property, something like this (note: pseudocode)

```
newRect.thePen := self.thePen.Clone();
etc...
```